# Using foreach inside a custom wordpress widget to escape and assign values to input

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code that is extracted from a custom widget I'm developing for a custom wordpress theme. 
I have a problem with the code, this because I want to use a foreach loop to escape the values by using the `esc_` functions that are built in in wordpress. 
I'm facing the problem that if I try to use the `$instance[$key]` to check if the value is set, if I `var_dump` I will see the value of the various keys of the array and not the key itself, so I'm not able to assign the key to the $instance variable. 
I also want to use the $key to set the relative variable like `$title` and `$claime` that are used after in my code.
How I can fix this?

to be more clear, what I expect is the following:

```
$instance = array( 'title' => 'lorem', 'claime' => 'ipsum' );

foreach( $instance as $key => $val ){
  // here the key I need is title so $instance[$key] needs to be $instance['title'] and $key become the $title variable.
  $key = isset( $instance[$key] )? esc_attr( $instance[$key] ) : ''; 
}
```

My actual code is:

```
foreach( $instance as $key => $val ){
      if( $key === 'text' ){
        $text = isset( $instance['text'] )? wp_kses( $instance['text'], $this->allowed ) : '';
      }
      #$key = isset( $instance[$key] ) ? esc_attr( $instance[$key] ) : '';
    }
```

Comment: I may be missing something here... but why are you checking if $instance['text '] isset? If its not set then $key === 'text' will never be true!?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make new variables from the array key's you can use php's extract function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

```
<?php
$var_array = array("color" => "blue", "size"  => "medium");

extract( $var_array );

echo $color, $size; // blue medium 
?>
```

But don't use this on arrays containing user input.